# There is at most one $K$-linear mapping $f:V\rightarrow V'$ such that $f(a_i)=a_i'$ for all $i$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

This statement is being proven in one of my textbooks, however I think it's not true:

---

Let $V$ be a $K$-Vectorspace with spanning set $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\}$, and $\{a_1', a_2', \cdots a_n'\}$ be a spanning set of another $K$-Vectorspace $V'$.

Then there is at most one $K$-linear mapping $f:V\rightarrow V'$ such that $f(a_i)=a_i'$ for all $i$.

---

Translated proof from Textbook:

Since $a$ has a representation of the form $a=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i a_i$, because of the linearity of $f$ we have:

\begin{equation}
f(a) = f\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i a_i \bigg) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i f(a_i)
\end{equation}
which means that $f$ is being uniquely represented by the values of $f(a_i)$, $ i=1, \cdots n$.

---

I don't understand why it follows that "$f$ is being uniquely represented" since $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\}$ is just a spanning set and not a basis, therefore the $\alpha_i$ don't have to be unique.

I also think I have a counterexample:

---

Let $a_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad V=\text{span}(a_1) \quad a_1' = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad V'=\text{span}(a_1') \quad$, and $f:V \rightarrow V'$ be a linear function.

Then any $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with the matrix representation
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & f_{12} \\ 1 & f_{22} \end{pmatrix}x
\end{equation}
fullfills that $f(a_i)=a_i'$ for all i, therefore $f$ can't be unique.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. Can you explain further regarding the dimensions? The initial problem has no restriction for the dimensions of $V$ and $V'$. And in my example $V$, and $V'$ are also vectorspaces since they are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Suppose that there exist two linear maps $f,\,g\colon V\to V'$ such that $f(a_i)=a_i',\,\,i=1,...,n$ and $g(a_i)=a_i',\,\,i=1,...,n$ and prove that $f=g.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then any $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with the matrix representation

But that's not the claim in the textbook. The claim is about "any $f:V\to V'$ ". In your example $V$ is a proper ($1$-dimensional) subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. And so is $V'$. These are not whole $\mathbb{R}^2$.

You are correct that there are many different $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(a_1)=a_1'$. Or in other words $f:V\to V'$ can be **extended** to many different linear maps $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. But again: that's not the claim.

Note that when you restrict this definition to $V$, then regardless of the choice of the matrix you will get the same function. Consider a simpler example:

$$f:k^2\to k^2$$
$$f(x,y)=(x,\lambda y)$$

for a fixed scalar $\lambda$. Now if you restrict it to $\{(x,0)\ |\ x\in k\}$ subspace, then the restriction is still given by $f(x,y)=(x,\lambda y)$. However $y=0$ implies $f(x,y)=(x,0)$ as well. On the subspace. So regardless of the choice of $\lambda$ we always get the same single function. And so different extensions can have equal restrictions.

This also means that there's a difference between "function" and "formula". A single function can (and actually always does) have many different formulas as mine and yours examples show. But the claim is about function, not formula.

> I don't understand why it follows that "$f$ is being uniquely represented" since $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\}$ is just a spanning set and not a basis, therefore the $\alpha_i$ don't have to be unique.

I think the wording in the textbook is indeed slightly confusing. But only slightly. It's not about $\alpha_i$ being unique. They don't have to be. You are right that they are unique only when this is a basis. And it does not have to be a basis.

It is about $f$ being unique. Meaning that if $g(a_i)=f(a_i)$ for all $i$, then $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

So again: it is about function uniqueness, not formula uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my example can't I just restrict the domain of $f$ to be $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, which then leads to range$(f)=V'$. Then we are back at $f:V\rightarrow V'$.

Comment: @haifisch123 yes, you can. And if you do that you will obtain the same single function **every** time. Regardless of the choice of matrix. This situation is similar to definining $f(x,y)=(x,ay)$. If you restrict that function to subspace generated by $(x,0)$ you will always get $f(x,0)=(x,0)$ function, regardless of the choice of $a$. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now; Even if I change the free parameters of the matrix the actuall mapping is uneffected, and therefore it's still the same function.

Comment: @haifisch123 the same on the subspace. Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is this:

> If you know what a linear transformation does on a spanning set, then you know what it does on any vector.

Why? Because if $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ span $V$, and you know that $f\colon V\to V'$ is a linear transformation, *and* you know what $f(a_1),\ldots,f(a_n)$ are, then there is only one thing that $f(v)$ can be for any $v\in V$. The reason is that you can express $v$ as a linear combination of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, and therefore $f(v)$ *must be* the corresponding linear transformation of $f(a_1),\ldots,f(a_n)$.

For instance, suppose you know that $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ has $f(1,1) = (1,2,3)$, $f(1,2) = (2,5,2)$, and $f(0,1) = (1,3,-1)$, and that $f$ is definitely linear. Given any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, say $(5,-2)$, you know you can write it as a linear combination of the vectors $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, and $(0,1)$ (in potentially many ways). For instance,
$$(5,-2) = 3(1,1) + 2(1,2) - 9(0,1).$$
That means that
$$\begin{align*}
f(5,-2) &= f\Bigl( 3(1,1) + 2(1,2) - 9(0,1)\Bigr)\\
 &= 3f(1,1) + 2f(1,2)-9f(0,1)\\
 &= 3(1,2,3) + 2(2,5,2) -9(1,3,-1)\\
 &= (-2,-11,22).
\end{align*}$$
There is no other possible value for $f(5,-2)$.

Even if we can write $(5,-2)$ a different way using $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, and $(0,1)$, if $f$ is really linear, we will get the same value using those other expressions. For instance, here we could also write
$$(5,-2) = 5(1,1) + 0(1,2) -7(0,1).$$
Using *that* expression, we get
$$f(5,-2) = 5f(1,1) -7f(0,1) = 5(1,2,3)-7(1,3,-1) = (-2,-11,22).$$

The fact that it's not a basis is why you have *"at most one"*, rather than *"exactly one"*. Because maybe there is *no way* reconcile the values you have. For instance, say my spanning set is now $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,1)$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$, and I take $f(1,0) = (1,1,1)$, $f(0,1) = (0,1,1)$, and $f(1,1) = (1,1,0)$. Well, now there is **no** linear transformation $f$ that does that, because if $f$ were linear it would have to satisfy
$$f(1,1) = f(1,0)+f(0,1)$$
but this does not happen with those values.

So we get:

> If you know what you want a linear tranformation to do on a spanning set, then there is at most one linear transformation that will do that; but in fact there may be no linear transformations that achieve it.

(Note that you do not need the $a_i'$ to be a spanning set.

Your example doesn't apply because it does not satisfy the assumptions: your functions $f$ are not maps from $V$ to $V'$; they are maps from larger vector spaces. It is always the case that if you have a linear transformation from a proper subspace $W$ of $V$ to $V'$, then there are several (always more than one, for sure, unless $V'$ is the zero vector space) different ways to extend it to a linear transformation from $V$ to $V'$ (that is, one that agrees with the one you started with on $W$).